# Отрисовка пузырей сообщений в чате на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, controls

Нужно нарисовать средствами WPF что-то подобное
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение, интерфейсом похожее на чат, что в приложении вк.
чтоб были сообщения от одного пользователя, а с другой стороны - от другого.

(сам механизм чата реализовывать мне не нужно),
Он будет подгружать переписку из источника и формировать истории. Одна страничка - одна история.

В общем, уважаемые гуру, мне очень нужен ваш совет по поводу того, какие средства использовать в WPF для этих целей.

Подскажите, в каком направлении искать, а я уж постараюсь двигаться самостоятельно.
После самостоятельного поиска, который дал не очень много, сформировались такие вопросы:

1. Какой контрол можно перерисовать в форме вот этих белых и зеленых
   фигур? Как это собственно делают нормальные люди (контрол кастомной
   формы)?
2. как внутрь поместить текст?
3. как рассчитать количество
   сообщений, которые помещаются на одну страничку.

И еще одно. У приложения должна быть страничная навигация (если я правильно понимаю смысл этого понятия)
Нужна кнопка, которая будет делать переход на следующую страничку и на предыдущую. как когда кликаешь NEXT и открывается следующий слайд.

Comment: _"нарисовать средствами WPF ... этих белых и зеленых фигур"_ -- создать фигуру можно с помощью [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx). выводится в контрол [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10):

Вам не нужен контрол кастомной формы. Вам просто нужно отрисовать облако с хвостиком нужного размера, и наложить текст внутри.

Возьмём исходную картинку и уберём из неё текст:

[image: bubble]

Это будет наш фон. Только надо, чтобы он изменял размеры не одинаково. Стандартная идея состоит в выделении нескольких областей:

[image: bubble с областями]

Угловые области не должны меняться вовсе, верхняя и нижняя боковые должны растягиваться по горизонтали, левая и правая боковые — по вертикали, а центральная — в обеих направлениях. Раз верхняя и нижняя боковые картинки будут всё равно растягиваться в ширину, можно сделать их шириной в один пиксель, и точно так же левую и правую боковые — высотой в один пиксель. Центральную область можно вовсе сделать 1х1.

Для реализации этого в WPF заведём `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChatInterface.Bubble"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <!-- сетка 3х3 -->
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="11"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="11"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="11"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- левый верхний уголок -->
        <Image Source="bubbleNW.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
        <!-- верхняя полоса -->
        <Image Source="bubbleN.png"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <!-- правый верхний уголок -->
        <Image Source="bubbleNE.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
        <!-- левая полоса -->
        <Image Source="bubbleW.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <!-- центр -->
        <Image Source="bubbleC.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <!-- и т. д. -->
        <Image Source="bubbleE.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Source="bubbleSW.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
        <Image Source="bubbleS.png"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Source="bubbleSE.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
               RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Теперь, нужно наложить на это текст. Абсолютно правильным путём было бы сделать декоратор с только что созданным контролом в фоне, но для этого нужны продвинутые знания WPF, так что мы пойдём более простым путём: заведём ещё один `UserControl`. Небольшая хитрость заключается в том, что облако должно быть такого же размера, как и текст, так что придётся использовать Binding, и чтобы Bubble не влиял сам на лэйаут, засунем его, например, в `Canvas`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChatInterface.BubbleWithText"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChatInterface"
             Name="root">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <local:Bubble
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=tb}"
                Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tb}"/>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBlock Name="tb" Padding="11" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=root}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

В code-behind нужно положить свойство `Text`:

```
public partial class BubbleWithText : UserControl
{
    public BubbleWithText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region dp string Text
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BubbleWithText));
    #endregion
}
```

Теперь можно засунуть наши элементы в `StackPanel`:

```
<StackPanel Width="150">
    <local:BubbleWithText Text="Я думаю, она дала тебе неправильный номер"/>
    <local:BubbleWithText Text="А может быть и нет, кто их разберёт?"/>
</StackPanel>
```

и получить следующее:

[image: результат]

Разумеется, исходные картинки лучше нарисовать самостоятельно (или потребовать у дизайнера), и ни в коем случае не сохранять в JPEG.

---

Если вы хотите сделать более правильно, используйте декоратор:

```
public class BubbleDecorator : Decorator
{
    Bubble bubble = new Bubble();

    public BubbleDecorator()
    {
        bubble.SetBinding(Bubble.WidthProperty, new Binding("ActualWidth")
                                                { Source = this });
        bubble.SetBinding(Bubble.HeightProperty, new Binding("ActualHeight")
                                                 { Source = this });
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        if (Child != null)
        {
            if (index == 0)
                return bubble;
            if (index == 1)
                return Child;
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Wrong child index");
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        bubble.Arrange(new Rect(arrangeSize));
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return Child == null ? 0 : 2; } }
}
```

Получаем такой XAML:

```
<StackPanel Width="150">
    <local:BubbleDecorator HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2">
        <TextBlock Padding="13" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Я думаю, она дала тебе неправильный номер"/>
    </local:BubbleDecorator>
    <local:BubbleDecorator HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2">
        <TextBlock Padding="13" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="А может быть и нет, кто их разберёт?"/>
    </local:BubbleDecorator>
    <local:BubbleDecorator HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2">
        <TextBlock Padding="13" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Приффки!!1"/>
    </local:BubbleDecorator>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: новый результат]

Comment: Э... Для совместного растягивания никакой магии не надо, достаточно положить и пузырь, и текст в один грид (без строк и столбцов). Ну и на отдельный контрол это никак не тянет, тут просится шаблон для какого-нибудь ContentControl. Заодно не будет ограничения на содержимое.

Comment: @Discord: Я пробовал, у меня пузырь хотел растянуться сильнее чем текст (не выяснил, почему, кажется, картинки странно стретчились), и таким образом получались пустые места под текстом.

Comment: @Discord: Я там написал в ответе, по-правильному нужен декоратор.

Comment: Декораторы-то зачем? У вас какая-то нездоровая привычка делать всё сложно.

Comment: @Discord: Декоратор — это вроде бы правильно, предписанный путь. Это по сути типа Border'а, элемент с одним child'ом, который его (child'а) кастомизирует. Bubble по сути и есть фигурный Border.

Comment: Не знаю, что в таком декорировании "предписанного". По-моему, единственная причина, почему Border является Decorator — это оптимизация. Так или иначе, добавил свою версию. Без всякой магии. :)

Comment: @Discord: Добавил декоратор. Неужели от сложнее, чем ваш стиль? Предписанность его в семантике: если нужно добавить «украшение» вокруг контента, это должно выглядеть как окружающий элемент, а не как стиль.

Comment: У вас есть какой-то код, какие-то движущиеся части, ветвления. У меня их нет. То есть код простой, конечно, но отсутствие кода ещё проще.

Comment: @Discord: Окей, может быть. В любом случае ContentControl со стилем менее семантично, чем `<local:BubbleDecorator><TextBlock .../></local:BubbleDecorator>`.

Comment: Один контрол семантичнее, чем два вложенных. Я могу сказать "вот эти content-контролы нарисовать обёрнутыми в пузыри" (объявлением стиля с ключом по умолчанию), а вы сказать "вот эти текст-блоки нарисовать обёрнутыми в пузыри" не можете.

Comment: @Discord: Почему не могу? У меня ж в примере как раз текстблоки оборачиваются в пузыри. (У вас, кстати, контентом может быть сложный XAML?) А семантичность в том, что разделяется декорация от контента, это хорошо.

Comment: Декорация должна быть в стиле. Вы же хромы кнопок, буллеты чекбоксов и прочие потроха наружу не вытаскиваете, вы только задаёте контент и стиль. / Контентом ContentControl — внезапно! — может быть что угодно. / В примере у вас юзер-контрол, а не декоратор. Ну вот лежат у вас стек-панели 20 текст-блоков. Обычные такие, вручную написанные, а не сгенерированные data template. Как вы скажете "обернуть все пузырями"? Только ручками каждый по отдельности оборачивать. Мне же будет достаточно определить стиль на уровне контейнера.

Comment: @Discord вот ему как раз будет достаточно объявить стиль, в котором и обернуть их все. А вам придется или копировать стиль из файла в файл - или же кидать его в глобальную свалку стилей.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Теперь вы будете мне рассказывать, что выделять стили в общие ресурсы — это плохо? о_О Вы б на досуге посмотрели, как реализованы стандартные контролы. И как они стилизуются.

Comment: @Discord: Это не от хорошей жизни. Лучше держать всё настолько локальным, насколько можно.

Comment: @VladD если у всего UI изменить zoom в + или -, то что будет со всеми png? искажений не будет?

Comment: @Stack: Будут. Если планируется такое, картинки нужны векторные (например, [`DrawingImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.DrawingImage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_8)).

Comment: @VladD подскажите как использовать данный контрол из кода, допустим пришло сообщение, получили его текст и что дальше?

Comment: @camtasia: Зависит от многих вещей. Если вы используете MVVM, то лучше вместо `StackPanel` использовать `ItemsControl` c `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @VladD я правильно понимаю, если использовать MVVM то сообщения должны добавляться в какой-нибудь "массив", а уже потом делается привязка этих данных. А если сообщение после принятия хранится просто в строке то как тогда его отобразить в пузыре?

Comment: @camtasia: Ну, если по MVVM, то сообщения кладутся в контейнер, например, массив строк. То есть если сообщение = строка, то у вас массив всех сообщений = массив строк, по идее проблем нет.

Comment: @camtasia: То есть если у вас MVVM, получится что-то такое: https://pastebin.com/EWF9hDPL. Если у вас не массив строк, а массив каких-то классов, то вместо `Text="{Binding}"` у вас будет привязка к полю: `Text="{Binding MessageText}"`, например.

Answer (score 7):

Идею с разрезанием картинки на 9 частей @Vlad разъяснил. Теперь я покажу, как то же самое сделать самым простым способом и в векторе. Отрисовка примитивная, в качестве примера. Обратите внимание на использование исключительно стилей, шаблонов и биндингов к свойствам контрола. Никакого кода в C#, никаких пользовательских контролов, никаких декораторов; на выходе только `ContentControl` с двумя стилями: для левого и правого пузыря.

```
<Window x:Class="SoRu479660.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Chat" Height="500" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Пузырь -->
        <Style x:Key="Bubble" TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Polygon Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Points="0 10, 10 0, 10 10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Polygon Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Points="0 0, 10 10, 0 10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Polygon Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Points="0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 8 8, 0 10, 5 5" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Polygon Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Points="0 0, 10 0, 0 10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- Текст с переносом строк -->
        <Style x:Key="WrapStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
        <!-- Текст в пузыре, левая версия -->
        <Style x:Key="BubbleLeftStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8 5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                            <Control Style="{StaticResource Bubble}" Background="LimeGreen"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrapStyle}"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <!-- Текст в пузыре, правая версия -->
        <Style x:Key="BubbleRightStyle" TargetType="ContentControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource BubbleLeftStyle}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                            <Control Style="{StaticResource Bubble}" Background="DeepSkyBlue" RenderTransformOrigin=".5 0">
                                <Control.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                                </Control.RenderTransform>
                            </Control>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrapStyle}"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleLeftStyle}"
                Content="Hello world!"/>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleLeftStyle}"
                Content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."/>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleRightStyle}"
                Content="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."/>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleRightStyle}"
                Content="Hello world!"/>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleLeftStyle}"
                Content="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."/>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource BubbleRightStyle}"
                Content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Выглядит результат так:

[image]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33800/discussion-on-answer-by-discord-------wpf).

Answer (score 2):

Вот вариант с декоратором на основе решения @VladD (пишу по памяти, возможны опечатки):

```
<UserControl x:Class="ChatInterface.Bubble"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="11"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="11"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="11"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="bubbleNW.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleN.png"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleNE.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleW.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleC.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleE.png"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleSW.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleS.png"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Source="bubbleSE.png" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                       RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" Stretch="None"/>

                <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Использование:

```
<local:Bubble>Привет, мир!</local:Bubble>

<local:Bubble>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Привет, мир!"/>
</local:Bubble>
```

Comment: У вас по сути урезанная версия моего варианта. :)

Comment: `UserControl` с темплейтом — интересная техника, не знал.

Comment: искажений не будет, если у всего UI изменить zoom в + или в - ?