# Уголок из блока. Дизайн и верстка Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Как сделать такой треугольник из блока как на сообщения?
[image: vk]

Comment: Это: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32500490/276994?

Comment: Или это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479660/10105?