# Кастомный стиль TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Как сделать вот такой стиль TextBlock`a?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Недавно было, сейчас найду.

Comment: Вот: [Отрисовка пузырей сообщений в чате на WPF](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479660/10105). Дубликат?

Comment: @VladD, Да, дубликат. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Тогда закрою.